# Keep media player working in background with screen off

Tags: java, android, background, android-mediaplayer

I've an streaming audio (from a server) with Media Player. It works when I turn off the screen and the system goes to sleep mode but after some minutes the phone stop music. This doesn't happen when the cellphone is connected to power (USB cable). So, the system must crash the app due to a power management or a memory management.

Service class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    PowerManager powerManager;
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
        wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");

    wakeLock.acquire();
    wifiLock.acquire();

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://mediacontrol.jargon.com.ar:8168/;");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        wakeLock.release();
        wifiLock.release();
    }
}
```

And this is the class that implements the service:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setRetainInstance(true); // con esto retenemos los valores pero se elimina el view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment4, container, false);

    play = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imagen=(ImageView) view.findViewById((R.id.imageView));

   if(comenzar) {
       play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

           }
   else {
      play.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
    }
       play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if (comenzar) {
                  if(isConnectedMobile(getActivity())|| 
isConnectedWifi(getActivity())) {
                       play.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);

getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                   getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class));
                   showNotification();
                   comenzar = false;
                   release=true;
               }
               else
               {
                   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                   builder.setTitle("No hay conexión a internet");
                   builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });

                   AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                   dialog.show();
               }
            } else {
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

                getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class));

                comenzar = true;
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                //getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);                
                release=false;
    }
        }

    });
    return view;
}
```

I also set this permission in the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

I can't debug it so well because the problem happens when the mobile is not connected but when the audio crash, then I connect it and it runs a one second more when I turn on the screen and after it stops.

I get this:

```
09-24 18:14:21.480 8539-8539/jaodev.utnfrp W/MediaPlayer: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
09-24 18:14:24.070 8539-8551/jaodev.utnfrp I/MediaHTTPConnection: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
09-24 18:14:24.970 8539-8539/jaodev.utnfrp D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
09-24 18:17:57.413 8539-8552/jaodev.utnfrp I/MediaHTTPConnection: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
09-24 18:18:30.437 8539-8551/jaodev.utnfrp I/MediaHTTPConnection: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
09-24 18:18:34.187 8539-9040/jaodev.utnfrp W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (703, 0)
09-24 18:18:34.188 8539-9040/jaodev.utnfrp W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)
09-24 18:19:03.462 8539-9040/jaodev.utnfrp I/MediaHTTPConnection: proxyName: 0.0.0.0 0
09-24 18:19:03.941 8539-9040/jaodev.utnfrp W/MediaHTTPConnection: readAt 1507328 / 32768 => java.net.ProtocolException
09-24 18:19:04.202 8539-8551/jaodev.utnfrp W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (703, 0)
09-24 18:21:51.201 8539-8544/jaodev.utnfrp I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=40KB, data=62KB
09-24 18:21:51.203 8539-8544/jaodev.utnfrp I/art: After code cache collection, code=40KB, data=62KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

Comment: Have a look here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427463/android-how-to-keep-my-music-playing-even-when-the-phone-is-lock-and-sleep

Comment: Thanks but I dont know how to implements android media session and link it whit media player. Due to media player gets audio stream from a server in the internet.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 please don't introduce the Android Studio tag on questions that have nothing to do with the IDE. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315195/when-to-remove-an-ide-tag and 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags

Comment: Hello all. The problem was solved using a foreground service and not a simple service.